# Pushing Ruby gems to own server so that it is publicly accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there any way to push Ruby gems to own sever? I want to make it publicly accessible (by an outside application). I have tried using geminabox but I have read that geminabox set up a sever to host gem within my organisation. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**USING GEMS FROM YOUR SERVER**

Use the gem sources command to add the gem server to your system-wide gem sources.

> gem sources --add http://localhost:9292

Then install gems as usual:

```
gem install secretgem
Successfully installed secretgem-0.0.1 1 gem installed
```

If you’re using Bundler then you can specify this server as a gem source in your Gemfile:

```
cat Gemfile
source "http://localhost:9292"
gem "secretgem"
bundle
Using secretgem (0.0.1)
Using bundler (1.0.13)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Extracted from [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use geminabox or simpler gem server, just create proxy ( use nginx )
and you could serve your gems world wide, Your customers should set source "your server " in their Gemfile.